# AutoFac - SingleInstance per dependency

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, autofac

Is it possible with AutoFac to have a `SingleInstancePerCondition()`.
I have two websites who run on a single IIS website and I would like to have 2 instances of my interface.

```
protected void Setup(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register(CreateBackofficeUserService)
        .As<IBackofficeUserService>()
        .SingleInstance()
}   

private static IBackofficeUserService CreateBackofficeUserService(IComponentContext context)
{
    var siteName = Context.GetSiteName();
    if (siteName == "SiteA")
        return new SiteABackofficeUserService();
    else if (siteName == "SiteB")
        return new SiteBBackofficeUserService();
    else
        return null;
}


public interface IBackofficeUserService
{
}

public class SiteABackofficeUserService : IBackofficeUserService
{
}

public class SiteBBackofficeUserService : IBackofficeUserService
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could register two instances by name:

```
builder.RegisterType<SiteABackofficeUserService>()
       .Named<IBackofficeUserService>("SiteA")
       .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<SiteBBackofficeUserService>()
       .Named<IBackofficeUserService>("SiteB")
       .SingleInstance();
```

and then access:

```
container.ResolveNamed<IBackofficeUserService>("SiteA");
```

Comment: Thank you,Is it still possible to inject those nammed parameters into my controller's constructor parameters?